# Why DominoDocumentData.setConcurrencyMode has no effect for Domino document data source?

Tags: xpages

I used to save the current DominoDocument of the XPage in some way like:

```
UIViewRootEx2 view=(UIViewRootEx2) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
DominoDocumentData ddd=(DominoDocumentData) view.getData().get(0);
DominoDocument dominoDoc=(DominoDocument) ddd.getDataObject();
//ddd.setConcurrencyMode("force");
dominoDoc.save();
```

To use the concurrencyMode property of the data source to avoid conflicts, I add the following line.

```
ddd.setConcurrencyMode("force");
```

I expect this behaves the same as setting the property in the XPage:

```
<xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Test" computeWithForm="onsave" concurrencyMode="force"></xp:dominoDocument>
```

But it fails. It always uses the value set in the XPage source and ignores the value set in the code. Anybody knows the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it fails". Does it throw an error? Does the code abort at that point. Or is it just ignored and the save continues? If the last option, please include the settings for the save button, because Submit type button saves all datasources regardless of any SSJS code added.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers, There is no error. It just uses the concurrencyMode value set in the XPage but not the one in the Java code. I use a normal button rather then a submit one.

Answer (score 0):

I would say: works as designed. During one of the [jsf phases](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html) the design is read and the value overwritten.

In JSF and thus XPages you don't mess from "Controller Code" (the stuff in your button) with the "View rendering" (your XPages source). You rather bind the property to your model (a scope variable is a good candidate) and let the runtime run its course.

So your code would be

```
<xp:dominoDocument var="document1"
              formName="Test"
       computeWithForm="onsave"
       concurrencyMode="#{viewScope.myConcurrency}">
</xp:dominoDocument>
```

and

```
viewScope.myConcurrency = "force"
```

Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I don't agree it works as designed. I know the JSF phases & MVC. Of the phases 1. Restore View 2. Apply Request Values 3. Process Validations 4. Update Model Values 5. Invoke Application 6. Render Response, my java code runs in the phase 5. It can read the current value of concurrencyMode, modify the document, save it and do all the things like that. But why cannot concurrencyMode be modified and work here?

Comment: The spec is sufficiently ambiguous to allow all sorts of things when it comes to data sources. I'm jsf you bind to beans which is different. Did you try with the computed property? If that works you have a solution.

Comment: Also I found: binding properties more reliable than trying to change them in code. Consider everything you put in a control to be part of the view component. In MVC we don't modify that, we modify the model.

Comment: I change the property concurrencyMode in a bean because I don't want to set it every time I add a document datasource. Checking conflicts should be an option rather than the default behavior. Simply saving the later version is much more often desired than creating a conflict. In classic notes web applications, we even have no way to defer the conflicts.  As to MVC, things about appearance, e.g. fonts, color, are VIEW, data sources are obviously MODELS. Java beans can be controllers or models based on what they do. There is NO reason a datasource property can only be set in view but not in code

Comment: Well the reason would be: because it has been implemented that way :-)

Comment: Digging a little deeper: the property concurrencyMode is read ONLY on page load. The datasource is initialized and concurrencyMode not subject to change. So in code change has no effect

Comment: Can you tell me more about your digging? How is the property made read only? I can write it a new value and read it in the bean. Have you found the XPages java source about it?

Comment: Weird behave. My code grabs the fresh instance of the document data source. I need the source code to understand this, yet I give it up.